# How to extract excel data from column to one .txt file separated with commas using python code?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a list of phone numbers in excel sheet column A, i need a python code to extract all the numbers to a .txt file in one line separated with commas.

[list of phone numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndnjK.png)

example: 560000000,560000001,560000003,560000004,560000005,560000006,560000007,560000008,560000009,560000010,560000011,560000012

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDQBL.png)

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service, please tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: as im developing a system so that i added my questing here to get the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook('1.xlsx')
sheet = book.active
first_column = sheet['A']
with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for x in range(len(first_column)):
        outfile.write(str(first_column[x].value)+',')
```

you can use `openpyxl` which is pretty much intuitive.

1. `load_workbook` opens your excel file specified in the `path`
2. we need to select the sheet
3. select the column in my case it is `A`
4. Open text file and iterate over the column to write the data into text file.

Comment: I have tried your code by i got the result in out.txt the numbers of the rows extracted, not the phone number.

Comment: @PythonAutomation modified

Comment: thank you... this is work perfect

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',  header=None)
print(','.join(map(str,df[0].to_list())))
```